# Formalizing the intuitive existential elimination

Tags: first-order-logic

I often see this informal inference rule being used in mathematics:

$$
\frac{\exists x\varphi}{\varphi\left[\frac ax\right]},
$$
where $a$ is the element of the model which satisfies $\varphi$. Since there exists some element such that $\varphi$ holds, we can do this, the reasoning goes. However, this approach has several problems:

1. This is mixing syntax with semantics, which is erroneous, as in the syntax of FOL, we do not have elements of the domain of models.
2. We can try to fix this issue by declaring that $a$ is a constant symbol. However, this fails again, because then $\exists x \varphi \vDash \varphi\left[\frac ax\right]$ does not hold, as this meta-theoretic statements ranges over all models, some of which satisfy the antecedent, but not the consequent, as they assign an "incorrect"/arbitrary value to $a$.

I am interested in how to formally ground this very useful intuitive inference. I would appreciate if the solution was extensible into multiple logical calculi (sequent calculus, natural deduction, Hilbert calculus and Fitch calculus come to mind) Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: In my opinion, the simplest way to ground it is via a conservativity principle: if $\Sigma$ is a language, $c$ is a constant symbol not in $\Sigma$, $\Gamma$ is a set of $\Sigma$-sentences, and $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma$-formula, then for every $\Sigma$-sentence $\psi$ we have $$\Gamma\cup\{\exists x\varphi(x)\}\vdash\psi\quad\iff\quad\Gamma\cup\{\varphi(c)\}\vdash\psi.$$ This is a straightforward exercise for any of the usual $\vdash$-notions, or for $\models$ in place of $\vdash$.

Comment: It's also a great motivator for sequent-based approaches, which make it very transparent via a rule of the type "From $\Gamma,\varphi[y/x]\vdash\Delta$ infer $\Gamma,\exists x\varphi\vdash\Delta$" with an appropriate freeness assumption on $y$. Things only get hairy if we insist on a too-naive interpretation of what sequents, and deductions of sequents, mean.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, though I was hoping for the constant symbol to show up in the consequent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, I think I've seen the rule from sequent calculus you referenced in Rautenberg's book on logic. I believe it's called anterior particularization.

Comment: Why do you want the constant symbol to appear in the consequent? The whole point is that it's separate from the actual goal, e.g. we introduce a new symbol to refer to an object of interest in the course of "proving $\psi$ from $\Gamma$" (that is, in the course of verifying the sequent $\Gamma\vdash \psi$) for some already-chosen $\Gamma,\psi$ that we care about. (Say, $\Gamma$ = the PA axioms and $\psi$ is Fermat's little theorem.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber My motivation was a bit different. For example, if we have $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \varphi (x))$ it is easy to *formally* derive Russell's paradox if we can simply substitute, say, $R$ for $y$. I noticed that this fails formality when I tried to do that, in fact.

In short, I'd like to have a similar rule in order to be able to construct formal proofs in my head more efficiently. It is a very common, but disturbingly informal, reasoning pattern.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, I tried doing your exercies, and $(\Rightarrow)$ looks fine, but $(\Leftarrow)$ seems false to me. I also don't see why we need a symbol from a new language. $(\Rightarrow)$ doesn't seem to require it. Maybe that's precisely what I'm missing for $(\Leftarrow)$ to make sense to me.

Comment: Why do you think $\Leftarrow$ is false? (Indeed, the language restriction is only required for $\Leftarrow$, so I suspect that's where you're making a mistake. Note that the target sentence $\psi$ is also a $\Sigma$-sentence, so it can't use $c$ either.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't think it's false, I just couldn't find a proof for it. As I see it, we need to get $\Gamma, \exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \Gamma, \varphi(c)$, which seems to be going from a general statement about the existence of an $x$ with a property $\varphi$ to the particular claim that some particular $c$ has that property, and is hence false.

Comment: Maybe try the semantic version (for $\models$ in place of $\vdash$) first, to convince yourself the goal is in fact correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was doing the semantic version all along. I guess I don't see the idea of extending the language with a constant symbol.

Comment: So in the semantic $\Leftarrow$ argument, you suppose that $\Gamma, \varphi(c)\models\psi$. This means by definition that every $\Sigma\sqcup\{c\}$-structure that satisfies $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi(c)\}$ also satisfies $\psi$. We now want to show, assuming this, that every $\Sigma$-structure satisfying $\Gamma\cup\{\exists x\varphi(x)\}$ also satisfies $\psi$. So suppose $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\Sigma$-structure satisfying $\Sigma\cup\{\exists x\varphi(x)\}$. Fix some $m\in\varphi^\mathfrak{M}$ and let $\mathfrak{M}'$ be the expansion of $\mathfrak{M}$ gotten by interpreting $c$ as $m$. (cont'd)

Comment: We have $\mathfrak{M}'\models\Gamma\cup\{\varphi(c)\}$ by assumption on $\mathfrak{M}$ and choice of $m$. So by our hypothesis *(= the RHS of $\Leftarrow$)* we get $\mathfrak{M}'\models\psi$. But $\psi$ doesn't involve the symbol $c$, so the reduct $\mathfrak{M}$ of $\mathfrak{M}'$ also satisfies $\psi$. So we're done. This "language-monotonicity" - if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a reduct of $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\theta$ is a sentence in the smaller language of $\mathfrak{A}$ then $\mathfrak{A}\models\theta\iff\mathfrak{B}\models\theta$ - is a useful and fundamental property of the semantic side of logic.

Comment: For other examples of language-juggling, look at applications of compactness (to show that FOL doesn't characterize up to isomorphism any infinite structure) and various definability results (think about Craig interpolation or Beth definability here).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, this makes sense. :) What do you think about my remark about Russell's antinomy being more easily derivable if we could put $\varphi[a/x]$ in the consequent for every formula $\exists x\varphi(x)$? After all, that was my original motivation.

Comment: I don't actually understand that remark, to be honest. If you write your proposed derivation of Russell's paradox in more detail, I might be able to respond to it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sure. Here it goes (I'm using inline notation to make typesetting easier for me): $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)) \Rightarrow \exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \notin x) \Rightarrow^{(!!)} \forall x (x \in R \leftrightarrow x \notin x) \Rightarrow R \in R \leftrightarrow R \notin R$ and a formal contradiction follows immediately if we also admit an axiom schema $/ \varphi \lor \neg\varphi$. $(!!)$ is the crucial part where my desired inference rule was used.

Comment: Isn't that just the usual argument around Russell's paradox?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I cannot (formally) swap the symbol $R$ with the variable $y$ for the reasons states in my OP. What I'd like to see is a formal implementation of this informal argument. On the other hand, assuming that $R$ is in the language, substitution with an universal quantifier *is* formally supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer:*

There is indeed a subtlety here. Given that, I think it's best to start from a solid understanding of the *semantic* situation.

Suppose I have a language $\Sigma$, a set of $\Sigma$-sentences $\Gamma$, a $\Sigma$-formula $\varphi(x)$, and a $\Sigma$-sentence $\psi$. Then - **fixing a new constant symbol $c\not\in\Sigma$** - we have the following "conservativity" fact:

> We have $$\Gamma\cup\{\exists x\varphi(x)\}\models\psi\quad\iff\quad \Gamma\cup\{\varphi(c)\}\models\psi.$$ (Moreover, if we do not assume $c\not\in\Sigma$, the $\Rightarrow$ direction still holds.)

The interesting part of this result is of course the $\Leftarrow$ direction, so let me prove that one in detail. I'll use the "language-monotonicity" of FOL, that whenever $\mathfrak{A}$ is a reduct of $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\theta$ is a sentence in the smaller language of $\mathfrak{A}$ then $\mathfrak{A}\models\theta\iff\mathfrak{B}\models\theta$; note that this is *not* a completely trivial property of logical systems (consider a logic with a quantifier for "Every definable element ...").

Assume that $$\Gamma\cup\{\varphi(c)\}\models\psi\quad\mbox{and}\quad \mathfrak{M}\models\Gamma\cup\{\exists x\varphi(x)\};$$ we want to show $\mathfrak{M}\models\psi$. Since $\mathfrak{M}\models\exists x\varphi(x)$, we can pick some $m\in\varphi^\mathfrak{M}$. Now consider the expansion of $\mathfrak{M}$ gotten by interpreting $c$ as $m$; call this $\mathfrak{M}'$. We have by choice of $m$ that $$\mathfrak{M}'\models\varphi(c),$$ and so by "language monotonicity" *upwards* from $\mathfrak{M}$ to $\mathfrak{M}'$ we get $$\mathfrak{M}'\models\Gamma$$ (since $\mathfrak{M}\models\Gamma$). By the first part of our assumption above (the RHS of the bi-implication we're trying to establish) we get $$\mathfrak{M}'\models\psi.$$ But now applying "language-monotonicity" *downwards* this time we get $$\mathfrak{M}\models\psi$$ as desired.

This sort of language-juggling can feel slippery at first. Here are a couple comments that might help:

- First, note that the "language-monotonicity" fact mentioned above is **not as trivial** as it may first appear! There are perfectly meaningful logics which lack it. For instance, consider the version of FOL augmented by a quantifier for "Every definable set ..." This quantifier is very sensitive to changes of language (consider e.g. shifting from $\{+\}$ to $\{+,\times\}$ in the context of $\mathbb{N}$), and so we lose language-monotonicity in a rather dramatic way. So even though language-monotonicity is not hard to prove (or even hard not to prove) for FOL, it is actually substantive.
- Second, there are more interesting examples of language-juggling that you'll see down the road. Compactness introduces some - there are lots of applications of compactness that require us to add a new constant, or even worse - and others appear in the context of results like Beth definability and Craig interpolation. Seeing more involved examples of a technique sometimes help demystify it.

---

Moving from semantics to syntax, the above intuitively tells us that we can safely introduce a new constant symbol in the course of a deduction to serve as a witness to an existential statement *as long as* we're careful about how that constant symbol appears/is used in the remaining steps of the deduction. Exactly how this caution is implemented will play out differently depending on the system used; personally I find sequent calculus the most intuitive (family of) approach(es), but one's mileage may vary.